# exterior derivative vs connection: $d= \theta^i\wedge\nabla_{e_i}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, connections

Let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection of a Rimannian manifold $M$, let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote an orthogonal local flame field of $TM$ and let $\theta^1,\dots,\theta^n$ be the its dual coflame. I would like to show that
$$d\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta^i\wedge\nabla_{e_i}\alpha $$
for any 1-form $\alpha$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_operator)). To do this, let $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\theta^i$ and $\theta^i=\sum_{j=1}^ng_j^idx^j$. Since the Levi-Civita connectin is torsion free, it follows
$$d\theta^i=\sum_{j=1}^n\theta^j\wedge\omega_j^i$$
where $\omega_i^j$ is the connection form of $\nabla$. So
$$\sum_i \theta^i\wedge\nabla_{e_i}\alpha=\sum_{i} \theta^i\wedge \left(d\alpha_i-\sum_j\alpha_j\omega_i^j\right) \\ 
=\sum_i\theta^i\wedge d\alpha_i-\sum_i\alpha_id\theta^i \\
=-\sum_i d\alpha_i\wedge\theta^i-\sum_i\alpha_id\theta^i \\
=-d\left(\sum_i\alpha_i\theta^i\right)=-d\alpha$$

Why is it incorrect?

Comment: I think your calculation is correct. There seems effectively a minus sign convention which allows to write $d$ more unambiguously as the operator $d=\theta^i\wedge \nabla_{e_i}\,.$ As the Wikipedia article shows this is one component of the Dirac operator $D=d-\delta\,.$ The Dirac operator is usually squared and the minus sign doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Oh wow... Thank you for your help!